# Vuejs how can I use Google Analytic,Facebook Pixel dynamically

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, facebook-pixel

I'm developing vuejs project that has many page for many customer, eg. www.sample.com/shopA, www.sample.com/shopB, www.sample.com/shopC

All shops use same file. and I would like to let each customer track their user separately. Is it possible to make vuejs file load Google Analytic,Facebook Pixel dynamically.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, in your case, is to insert a different tracking code for each shop, `directly` in the code of each section or with a `case`.

Comment: Do you have any example, Regards.

Comment: You can find conditional example in the documentation, the directive v-if is used to conditionally render a block. The block will only be rendered if the directive’s expression returns a truthy value: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html